# Fixing Reference Error in an Equation that isn't obviously wrong

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

=(C2/(B2(B2-C2)))

This equation returns a Reference error. [This is a link to an image of the table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXLPn.png) The referenced numbers are just numbers (i.e., not equations). When I try to check the point in the calculation in which the error results, I'm not sure what the problem is. Here is the [calculation before the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHV3a.png) and here is the [calculation after the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbNL5.png). Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel it is necessary to show multiplication with the star (*)

Use instead here:

```
=(C2/(B2*(B2-C2)))
```

The underline error in your picture occurs directly after the missing star symbol.

I think this will do it for you

Comment: i can't believe that was the problem. thank you.